# Proving that a matrix is idempotent

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations, idempotents

My task was to show that certain matrices are idempotent, that is,  ${AA} = {A}$. I struggled with the proof for one case and when I look at the solution, I have problems understanding one step.

Prove that the matrix $I_n - A (A^TA)^{(-1)}A^T $ is idempotent:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split} 
& I_n - A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T) \times (I_n - A(A^T A)^{-1} A^T) \\
&= I_n -2A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T + A(A^TA)^{-1} A^TA(A^TA)^{-1} A^T \\
& = I_n -2A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T + A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T \\
& = I_n - A (A^TA)^{-1}A^T
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

I am struggling to follow why $A(A^TA)^{-1} A^TA(A^TA)^{-1} A^T \Rightarrow A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T$ in step 2 to 3.

Comment: Very nice question, +1!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By associativity, notice that:
\begin{align*}
A(A^TA)^{-1} A^TA(A^TA)^{-1} A^T
&= A(A^TA)^{-1} \left[(A^TA)(A^TA)^{-1}\right] A^T \\
&= A(A^TA)^{-1} \left[I_n\right] A^T \\
&= A(A^TA)^{-1} A^T \\
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh, that looks really nice, thanks a lot! Problem solved :)